# Pipeline management in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipeline, file-descriptor

i'm currently looking how pipelining is managed into shells.
for example, in my shell, if i enter "ls | wc | less". The result of this operation will be the creation of three process, ls wc and less.
Ouput of ls will be piped to the enter input of wc, and the ouput of wc will be piped to the enter intput of less.

For me, it means that during the execution of "ls | wc | less". The standard input of less will not be the keyboard, but the ouput of wc. But, less will still be responsive to my keyboard. Why ? I don't understand, because for me, less should not be sensitive to the keyboard since it have been piped.

Do somebody have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Do not conflate stdin with a tty.  Often, the tty is associated with the stdio streams of a process.  More frequently, it is not.  This is a great question, and a good demonstration of the distinction between the tty and stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from less

```
#if HAVE_DUP
    /*
     * Force standard input to be the user's terminal
     * (the normal standard input), even if less's standard input 
     * is coming from a pipe.
     */
    inp = dup(0);
    close(0);
#if OS2
    /* The __open() system call translates "/dev/tty" to "con". */
    if (__open("/dev/tty", OPEN_READ) < 0)
#else
    if (open("/dev/tty", OPEN_READ) < 0)
#endif
        dup(inp);
#endif
```

It opens a direct stream from /dev/tty as well as whatever your stdin is.

Comment: Does it means that less is still reading from wc output AND from /dev/tty ?

Comment: Yes. The data it reads from its standard input (which is the pipe whose other end is used as the standard output of `wc`) is what it writes its standard output. The data it reads from `/dev/tty` is what it interprets as interactive commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess - less is opening `/dev/console` for the interactive session, I used that trick once. I was wrong - `strace` is your friend :-):

```
echo | strace less

) = 16
read(0, "\n", 8192)                     = 1
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
read(0, "", 8191)                       = 0
write(1, "\33[7m(END)\33[27m\33[K", 17(END)) = 17
read(3,
```

As you can see, less is reading from FD 3.

```
/* Standard file descriptors.  */
#define STDIN_FILENO    0   /* Standard input.  */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1   /* Standard output.  */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2   /* Standard error output.  */
```

And a closer look (after 'q') shows:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY)              = 3
```

Which confirms @123's source code inspection - it opens `/dev/tty`.